# nagios check_snmp ifoperstatus not OK

Tags: snmp, nagios, net-snmp, check-snmp

I'm reading [Monitoring Routers and Switches](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-routers.html) page, in particular "Monitoring SNMP Status Information" section.

quote:

> In the example above, the "-o ifOperStatus.1" refers to the OID for
>   the operational status of port 1 on the switch. The "-r 1" option
>   tells the check_snmp plugin to return an OK state if "1" is found in
>   the SNMP result (1 indicates an "up" state on the port) and CRITICAL
>   if it isn't found. The "-m RFC1213-MIB" is optional and tells the
>   check_snmp plugin to only load the "RFC1213-MIB" instead of every
>   single MIB that's installed on your system, which can help speed
>   things up.

So, I'm trying out their example:

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp --hostname=X.X.X.X --community=X --protocol=X --oid=ifOperStatus.5 -r1 -m RFC1213-MIB
SNMP OK - 1 | RFC1213-MIB::ifOperStatus.5=1 
#
```

interface returns `SNMP OK - 1` - interface is "up". I took another of interface down and ran same command for that interface.

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp --hostname=X.X.X.X --community=X --protocol=X --oid=ifOperStatus.6 -r1 -m RFC1213-MIB
SNMP OK - 2 | RFC1213-MIB::ifOperStatus.6=2 
# 
# snmpwalk -Os -cX -vX X ifOperStatus.6
ifOperStatus.6 = INTEGER: down(2)
#
```

returns `SNMP OK - 2` - interface is down

I can't figure out how to get `-r1` to work properly, because even though it sees that interface is down, it passes to Nagios as its OK. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: check_snmp v1.4.15 (nagios-plugins 1.4.15)

Comment: no, sorry( I don't feel comfortable running executable from a 3rd party sites on my computer, not to mention it may not be even compatible w/ my system at the first place.

Comment: there seems to be a bug (or I'm doing something really wrong) `-r1` isn't working for me, I was able to get it going through `-c1` instead.

Comment: @user2196728 don't get so disappointed) it only makes sense _NOT_ to run executable from sources that you don't trust))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as "work around" (even though it really not), one can use `-c` or `-w` instead of `-r`, as `-r` seems to have some sort of bug.

```
# ./check_snmp --help | grep -E 'critical|warning'
 -w, --warning=THRESHOLD(s)
 -c, --critical=THRESHOLD(s)
#
```

example:

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp --hostname=X.X.X.X --community=X --protocol=X --oid=ifOperStatus.6 -c1
SNMP CRITICAL - *2* | IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.5=2 
#
```

Comment: .. same thing, I think the problem is it doesn't do _ANY_ matching at all, I can do `-ruser2196728` and it'll still say `OK`

Comment: @user2196728 yeah, I already found it too) so I was right, it _IS_ a bug)

Comment: dude, take it easy there) you going give yourself a heart attack( i was trying to get it going and I wasn't sure 100% if I was doing it right or wrong so I came here to ask community (which you're part of) at the end of the day solution is in place, so it's all good). I'd like to thank _YOU_ personally for your time and help)